# google maps response starts with 'b', how can I retrieve the data?

Tags: python, google-maps

I tried to get some data from a Google maps request; it returned the following data. It starts with a 'b' character somehow:

```
b'{
    \n "destination_addresses" : [ "Toronto, ON, Canada" ],
    \n "origin_addresses" : [ "Ottawa, ON, Canada" ],
    \n "rows" : [\n {
        \n "elements" : [\n {
            \n "distance" : {
                \n "text" : "450 km",
                \n "value" : 449678\n
            },
            \n "duration" : {
                \n "text" : "4 hours 14 mins",
                \n "value" : 15229\n
            },
            \n "status" : "OK"\n
        }\n ]\n
    }\n   ],
    \n   "status" : "OK"\n
}\n'
```

Then I tried to get a value from the data, it errors because of the 'b' at the beginning. If I remove the 'b', it works fine:

```
response = str(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
result = json.loads(response.replace('\\n', ''))
```

Is there a way in Python to retrieve the values without removing the 'b'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the `b`, it just indicates that it's a [bytes literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal).

Anyway it sounds like you're using Python3, since in Python2, this works fine:

```
res = b'{\n "destination_addresses" : [ "Toronto, ON, Canada" ],\n "origin_addresses" : [ "Ottawa, ON, Canada" ],\n "rows" : [\n {\n "elements" : [\n {\n "distance" : {\n "text" : "450 km",\n "value" : 449678\n },\n "duration" : {\n "text" : "4 hours 14 mins",\n "value" : 15229\n },\n "status" : "OK"\n }\n ]\n }\n ],\n "status" : "OK"\n}\n'
json.loads(res)
```

In Python3 you would have to decode the bytes into a character set, or remove the b, like you're doing:

```
json.loads(res.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple!
I'm assuming you are using python requests library.

```
response = requests.get(url,headers)
```

now if your output contains **b** that means its `byte literal`

just convert it to **json** like that

```
response = response.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to decode the bytes object to string as :

```
result  = json.loads(response.decode("utf-8"))
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: oh someone just answered the same :P

Comment: That's why they call you the flash I guess ;)